Looking for moderately recent fantasy short works about a cemetery custodian
In the last few years, I recall reading a series of short works about a young woman who, to get our of her parents' house, takes a job as a caretaker at a cemetery.  The compensation includes a living space. Perhaps 'of course', there turns out to be more to it than learning to mow the grass. Her supervisor is a rather mysterious fellow who progressively involves her in more and more of the tasks of looking after the, um, 'residents'. It was not profound, but I recall enjoying the particular treatment, and I'd like to track them down.

The Groundskeeper: Raking Up the Dead by Cedar Sanderson.


The ghouls, wraiths, and ghosties had not been part of the job description. Or maybe they had, just not in so many words. The neatly printed sign next to the ornate gates had simply read “Cemetery groundskeeper and caretaker needed. Inquire within."
Now Chloe's trying to calm an irascible ghoul, help a lost ghost find his way back to his grave, and get the mowing done before she needs to break out the bush hog instead... Who knew being a groundskeeper meant trying to keep things in the ground?

This is the first book in the Raking up the Dead series, and as you say it's barely even a novella at 57 pages. The other two books in the series are 40 and 101 pages.
I found this on the Goodreads site using the search: caretaker cemetery fantasy site:goodreads.com/book/show/. The Goodreads site is always a good starting point for finding books.
